# Как после загрузки снимка экрана в файл проанализировать его в пикселях?

Tags: java, screenshots

Как после загрузки скриншота с экрана в файл его анализировать в пикселях ?

`javax.imageio.ImageIO` - умеет грузить картинки как объекты `BufferedImage`.
`javax.swing.JLabel` - умеет отображать иконки.
`javax.swing.ImageIcon` - умеет загружать картинки как иконки.
`BufferedImage` - там есть методы манипуляции с пикселями, а вот как проводить анализ - уже сложнее.